# How to redirect parent widget focus to a child widget?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget, focus

There's a simple class called `FloatingPointPropertyEditor`. It's inherited of `QWidget` and contains of one `QLineEdit` instance with a floating point number validator.

```
class FloatingPointPropertyEditor : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // ...

private:
    QLineEdit* m_lineEdit;
};
```

The problem is that I have to redirect the focus of a `FloatingPointPropertyEditor` instance to the inner `QLineEdit` instance and select all the text in there. That is, when a `FloatingPointPropertyEditor` gets a focus, the user already can enter the text in the `QLineEdit` instance without clicking to it before. Could you please explain how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

From Qt. doc. about [`QWidget::focusPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop):

> focusPolicy : Qt::FocusPolicy
>
> This property holds the way the widget accepts keyboard focus
>
> The policy is Qt::TabFocus if the widget accepts keyboard focus by tabbing, Qt::ClickFocus if the widget accepts focus by clicking, Qt::StrongFocus if it accepts both, and Qt::NoFocus (the default) if it does not accept focus at all.
>
> You must enable keyboard focus for a widget if it processes keyboard events. This is normally done from the widget's constructor. For instance, the QLineEdit constructor calls setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus).
>
> If the widget has a focus proxy, then the focus policy will be propagated to it.

Concerning the mentioned focus proxy, about [`QWidget::setFocusProxy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocusProxy):

> void QWidget::setFocusProxy(QWidget *w)
>
> Sets the widget's focus proxy to widget w. If w is nullptr, the function resets this widget to have no focus proxy.
>
> Some widgets can "have focus", but create a child widget, such as QLineEdit, to actually handle the focus. In this case, the widget can set the line edit to be its focus proxy.
>
> setFocusProxy() sets the widget which will actually get focus when "this widget" gets it. If there is a focus proxy, setFocus() and hasFocus() operate on the focus proxy.

**TL;DR**:

The default focus policy of `QWidget` is `Qt::NoFocus`, the default for `QLineEdit` is `Qt::StrongFocus`. With this, it should work out of the box (although the doc. about `setFocusProxy()` makes this IMHO not obvious).

To be sure, I made a small demo `testQWidgetFocus.cc`:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class Editor: public QWidget {

  private:
    QHBoxLayout _qHBox;
    QLineEdit _qEdit;
    QPushButton _qBtn0;

  public:
    Editor(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr):
      QWidget(pQParent),
      _qBtn0(">|<")
    {
      _qHBox.addWidget(&_qEdit, 1);
      _qBtn0.setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus); 
      _qHBox.addWidget(&_qBtn0);
      setLayout(&_qHBox);
      // signal handler
      connect(&_qBtn0, &QPushButton::clicked,
        [&](bool) { _qEdit.clear(); });
    }
    virtual ~Editor() = default;
    Editor(const Editor&) = delete;
    Editor& operator=(const Editor&) = delete;

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget qWinMain;
  QFormLayout qForm;
  QLineEdit qEdit1;
  qForm.addRow("QLineEdit:", &qEdit1);
  Editor qEdit2;
  qForm.addRow("Editor:", &qEdit2);
  qDebug() << "qEdit2.focusPolicy():" << qEdit2.focusPolicy();
  qDebug() << "qEdit2.focusProxy():" << qEdit2.focusProxy();
  Editor qEdit3;
  qForm.addRow("Editor:", &qEdit3);
  qWinMain.setLayout(&qForm);
  qWinMain.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output: (compiled in VS2017, Qt 5.13)

```
Qt Version: 5.13.0
qEdit2.focusPolicy(): Qt::NoFocus
qEdit2.focusProxy(): QWidget(0x0)
```

[image: Snapshot of testQWidgetFocus]

<kbd>**⇄**</kbd>

[image: Snapshot of testQWidgetFocus (after pressing Tab)]

<kbd>**⇄**</kbd>

[image: Snapshot of testQWidgetFocus (after pressing Tab)]

Output: (compiled in cygwin64)

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.4.0

$ qmake-qt5 testQWidgetFocus.pro

$ make && ./testQWidgetFocus  
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQWidgetFocus.o testQWidgetFocus.cc
g++  -o testQWidgetFocus.exe testQWidgetFocus.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
qEdit2.focusPolicy(): Qt::FocusPolicy(NoFocus)
qEdit2.focusProxy(): QWidget(0x0)
```

[image: Snapshot of testQWidgetFocus (in X11)]

<kbd>**⇄**</kbd>

[image: Snapshot of testQWidgetFocus (after pressing Tab)]

<kbd>**⇄**</kbd>

[image: Snapshot of testQWidgetFocus (after pressing Tab)]

**Note:**

I changed the focus policy of the involved `QPushButton`. So, it is skipped in Tab-jumping (but still can be used by mouse click). Without changing its focus policy, it is considered in Tab-jumping as well.

---

Build scripts:

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(QWidgetFocus)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_executable(testQWidgetFocus
  testQWidgetFocus.cc)
target_link_libraries(testQWidgetFocus
  Qt5::Widgets)

# define QT_NO_KEYWORDS to prevent confusion between of Qt signal-slots and
# other signal-slot APIs
target_compile_definitions(testQWidgetFocus PUBLIC QT_NO_KEYWORDS)
```

`testQWidgetFocus.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQWidgetFocus.cc

QT += widgets
```